# Ruby conditional formatting get badRequest: Invalid requests[0]: No request set. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a Google Sheets. This is the code based on the Google API documentation for Ruby, conditional formatting and the Ruby Doc (very poor).

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting
- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/SheetsV4/Sheet#conditional_formats-instance_method

So far I did not find ANY full documentation on how to adapt the code to Ruby.

The terminal returns:

> `check_status': badRequest: Invalid requests[0]: No request set. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Do you have any idea of how to make this code work?

```
requests.push({
      add_conditional_formats: {
        rule: {
          ranges: [
            {
              sheet_id: 0, start_column_index: 9, end_column_index: 100,
            }
          ],
          gradient_rule: {
            minpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.2,
                red: 0.8
              },
              type: "MIN"
            },
            maspoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.9
              },
              type: "MAX"
            },
          }
        },
        index: 0
      },
      add_conditional_formats: {
        rule: {
          ranges: [
            {
              sheet_id: 0, start_column_index: 9, end_column_index: 100,
            }
          ],
          gradient_rule: {
            minpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.2,
                red: 0.8
              },
              type: "NUMBER",
              value: 0
            },
            maspoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.9
              },
              type: "NUMBER",
              value: 256
            },
          }
        },
        index: 1
      }
    })

    body = {requests: requests}
    result = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, body, {})
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike just saw your reply. I will check that this week end and get back to you :) Thanks !

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to wait for it.

Comment: it works ! thank you so much !

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this modification? This modified script supposes that your access token can be used for updating spreadsheet.

#### Modification points :

- `add_conditional_format_rule` is one request. So in your case, the array of `requests` is required to be 2 elements, because you are using 2 `add_conditional_format_rule` in the requests.
- `maspoint` is `maxpoint`.
- `add_conditional_formats` is `add_conditional_format_rule`.
- Value of `sheet_id` is string.
- Value of `value` of `gradient_rule` is string.

#### Modified script :

```
requests = []
requests.push({
      add_conditional_format_rule: {
        rule: {
          ranges: [
            {
              sheet_id: "0", start_column_index: 9, end_column_index: 100,
            }
          ],
          gradient_rule: {
            minpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.2,
                red: 0.8
              },
              type: "MIN"
            },
            maxpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.9
              },
              type: "MAX"
            },
          }
        },
        index: 0
      }
    },{
      add_conditional_format_rule: {
        rule: {
          ranges: [
            {
              sheet_id: "0", start_column_index: 9, end_column_index: 100,
            }
          ],
          gradient_rule: {
            minpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.2,
                red: 0.8
              },
              type: "NUMBER",
              value: "0"
            },
            maxpoint: {
              color: {
                green: 0.9
              },
              type: "NUMBER",
              value: "256"
            },
          }
        },
        index: 1
      }
    })

body = {requests: requests}
result = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, body, {})
```

#### Reference :

- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.